# With ASP.NET, how do I make display names of properties show in lower case in validation error messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

In ASP.NET, what is the best way to display field/property names in form validation error messages in lower case?

For example, if I have a `Price` property on a model, and `Price` is not nullable, and I leave the `Price` field blank when filling out a form for this model, then I will get this error message on the form:

> The Price field is required.

"Price" is capitalised. Is there any easy way to make it lower case, like the following?

> The price field is required.

There must be a way of making these property names show in lower case for every error message. Because yes, if I just wanted it for one property, then I could set a custom error message using the `Required` attribute:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The price field is required.")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to make these property names show in lower case by default for every error message?

I did find [this question with some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855740/asp-net-mvc-validation-return-lowercase-property-name), but the solutions seem pretty complex, and also that person is talking about JSON serialisation, which is a bit different to my case.

Thanks if anyone can share any info on this problem.

Comment: Hi @toshiba192301,It works fine in my project. Could you pls share what is your version asp.net core? Did you use mvc? What if you use `[Display(Name ="price")]`?

Comment: @Rena, I am using .NET 7.0. And yes it's an ASP.NET MVC application. If I use `[Display(Name = "price")]` then yes, it changes the error message to the desired format, making "price" lower case. But it will also change the form input label to be lower case as well, which is unfortunate, because preferably I want that to retain its initial capital letter. [See this picture](https://i.imgur.com/3FEYbPU.png) - the "price" label is fully lower case, while the other labels are capitalised.

Comment: Hi @toshiba192301,Yes, if you use Display attribute it is the expected result, I just want to know if the attribute work or not. And I also tried .NET 7, still working fine. Could you pls share your whole view and model which could help me reproduce your issue? Also check your `Required` attribute if it actually exists in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.

Comment: Hi @Rena - yes the `Display` attribute works, but like I say, it will make the form input label lower case too, showing as "price" instead of "Price", but I would like the label to still say "Price". I suppose I could get rid of `<label asp-for="Price"...` in the view, and replace it with a standard HTML `<label>` element with "Price" capitalised. But that's not an ideal solution... because then for every single property, I would have to define the `Display` attribute in the model, and replace the `<label>` code in the view.

Comment: Also @Rena - you wanted the view and model code, so here they are: [view](https://i.imgur.com/mONgwa0.png) and [model](https://i.imgur.com/AkDMKbD.png). In the view I've replaced the `<label>` element with the `asp-for` attribute with just a standard HTML `<label>` as I mentioned in the last comment. Like I say, it works, but it's not an ideal solution really... anyway thanks for your efforts to help. Maybe I will need to do more research to find if there's a solution of the kind I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ValidationMessageFor` on the page like this

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)
```

It will show the error message in a `span` with the class `field-validation-error`.
So if you now the class you can use css to transform the text to lowercase.

```
<style>
    .field-validation-error {
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering, I appreciate it. It's not quite what I mean though... if I use your method, then the error message will show as "the price field is required" (all lower case, including the beginning of the sentence). What I am trying to do is make it say "The price field is required" (capital "T" at the beginning of the sentence). I just want the property display name (in this case "price") to be in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<style>
    .field-validation-error {
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    .field-validation-error:first-letter {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I appreciate it. Your solution does indeed work. I was hoping to find a way to get ASP.NET to produce the error messages in the desired format, rather than having to hack it with CSS, but maybe I will have to do a lot of searching and googling to find a way to do that. Thanks for giving a working solution.